# Is it safe to mix Java streams + Rxjava

Tags: java, java-stream, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Assuming i have an observable and somewhere downstream I chose to filter using java 8 streams instead of using rxjava operators.
Will this cause any issues?

```
 List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.just(stringList)
            .map(new Function<List<String>, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> apply(List<String> strings) throws Exception {
                    return strings.stream().filter(it -> it.contains("randomText"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
            }).subscribe(new Consumer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<String> strings) throws Exception {
            //do something with list
        }
    });
```

Comment: why do you use RxJava here? You can write straightforward Java stream sentence like stringList.stream().filter() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Consumer<T>` accepts `T`, so you can use all the methods provided by `T`.

Anyway check the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html), RxJava provides several operators, like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc. For example, you can replace in your code the first `map` as follows:

```
Observable.fromIterable(stringList).filter(x -> x.contains(RANDOM_TEXT))
```